# Bigger Interval in which ivp has a differentiable solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

find the bigger interval in which the ivp has a differentiable solution, there is no need to solve the equation.

[image: DE]

I know that the the problem has unique solution in the interval $(-2,2)$, but how know in which interval the solution is differentiable ?

Is it enough solve the equation for $y'$ and see where it is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is  subtler than it looks.  You are correct that there is guaranteed to be a solution in the interval $(-2,2)$, and it is differentiable there (in fact analytic there).  It's not so obvious that the solution in $(-2,2)$ **doesn't** join
up differentiably with a solution in $(2,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,-2)$.  Note that
at $t=2$ the equation reduces to $4y = 12$.
If you had a solution where $y \to 3$ as $t \to 2$, this could be the case.
In fact, all solutions do have $y \to 3$ as $t \to 2$, and they do extend
continuously past $t=2$.  However, it turns out they are not differentiable at $t=2$.  Namely, the general solution in $(-2,2)$ is

$$ y(t) = \left( {t}^{2}-4 \right)  \left( -3/8\,\ln  \left( 2-t \right) +3/8\,
\ln  \left( t+2 \right) +3/4\, \left( t+2 \right) ^{-1}+3/4\, \left( t
-2 \right) ^{-1}+c \right) 
$$

A similar formula applies in $(2,\infty)$ or $(-\infty,-2)$ but with 
$\ln(2-t)$ or $\ln(2+t)$ changed to $\ln(t-2)$ or $\ln(-2-t)$ respectively.

Note that this has $y \to 3$ as $t \to 2-$.  But because of the term in $\ln(2-t)$, it won't be differentiable at $t=2$, i.e.

$$\lim_{t \to 2-} \dfrac{y - 3}{t - 2} = \infty$$

A similar thing happens at $t=-2$.

To see what could go wrong, try the  differential equation

$$(t-2) y' = 2 t - 2 - y$$

where you are guaranteed solutions exist in $(-\infty, 2)$, but in fact
$y = t$ is a solution on all of $(-\infty,\infty)$.